# Jquery datepicker show on div mouseover, hide on mouseout from datepicker

Tags: jquery, date, datepicker, hover

Im trying to achive that effect: http://www.palms.com/ (look at booking module on right side of site). When u place cursor at div for ex Arriving, it will show you datepicker, u can rollover on it, and pick a date. When u rollout from div or datepicker, its disapears. Thats a problem, whose i cant achive.

I can show datepicker on mouseover, but i cant hide it on mouseover (from datepicker), when im rollout from div, datepicker disapears...

Its my test code:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('#calendar').datepicker();
        $('#calendar').hide();
        $('#calendar').addClass('abs');

        $('#content').mouseover(function(){
            $('#calendar').fadeIn('fast');
        });

        $('#content').mouseout(function(){
            $('#calendar').fadeIn('fast');
        });
    });
</script>

...

<div id="content">
     <div class="field" id="test">
          PICKUP A DAY
     </div>
     <div id="calendar"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: In your mouseout function you're telling the calendar to fadeIn, it should be fadeOut.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to hide the datePicker on **`mouseout`**, then you should have used **`fadeOut()`** like this

```
$('#content').mouseout(function(){
            $('#calendar').fadeOut('fast');
        });
```

Check this in [**JSFiddle1**](http://jsfiddle.net/3StJd/1/)

But my opinion is to use **`.hover()`** with a *callback* like this for a *smooth effect*

```
$('#content').hover(function(){
      $('#calendar').fadeIn('fast');
  }, function() {
      $('#calendar').fadeOut('fast');
});
```

You can check this in [**JSFiddle2**](http://jsfiddle.net/3StJd/)